# SQL query statement in PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, sql

I hava a problem using SQL query in PHP, I've tried to find out what wrong about my code, anyway this code work well in SQL query via phpMyAdmin and show the result correctly

When I use the condition **WHERE RoomNo ='D003'** or any Room No. (I tried both 'D003' and "D003") it doesn't query anything at all

Please help.

Here is my code

```
onclick = "javascript: openListOfValue('ADD_LINE','Room','Select RoomNo, RoomType FROM Room WHERE RoomNo ="D003"','RoomNo,RoomType');
```

---

```
<script>
function openListOfValue(mode, table, initSQL, columnname){
    window.open("listofvalue.php?mode="+mode+"&table="+table+"&initSQL="+initSQL+"&columnname="+columnname,"popup","width=600,height=350");
}
</script>
```

Comment: `RoomNo ="D003"',` -> see the quotes, you can escape them with a backslash; are you sure that you want allow `listofvalue.php` to execute every query the client want? I hope you don't.

Answer (score 0):

SQL string literals are quoted with single quotes.

As your HTML string literal uses double quotes, you are using single quotes for your Javascript string literal. In order to have single quotes inside this string you must escape them. In Javascript you use the backslash to escape a single quote:

```
onclick = "javascript: openListOfValue('ADD_LINE','Room',
  'Select RoomNo, RoomType FROM Room WHERE RoomNo = \'D003\'','RoomNo,RoomType');"
```

Comment: Thanks, Thorsten Kettner
I already tried and it also work but the result is "No data found"
(Window popup correctly but search result not found)

What should I do next ?

Comment: I don't know. Debug your listofvalue.php maybe to see how it evaluates the strings and what it does with them?